# What type of Boolean logic circuit is this?

Tags: digital-logic

I need help confirming some hunches.  I'm trying to figure out what type of circuit this is:

[image: diagram]

Any ideas?
Also, I think the logic expression for this is:
`D = (A AND B) OR (NOT(B) AND C)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are only two intermediate signals, so it's relatively easy to break down.  We'll call the left input to the bottom `OR` gate `X` and the right input `Y`.

I'm going to use some shorthand here - `NOT` = `!`, `AND` = `&`, `OR` = `|`.

```
X = A & B

Y = !B & C
```

Those two lead into the `OR` gate that produces D:

```
D = (A & B) | (!B & C)
```

Which is the result you came up with, so you are correct.

One application of this logic circuit is to act as a selector:

- When `B` is asserted, then `A` is output on `D`, and `C` is ignored.
- When `B` is de-asserted, then `C` is output on `D`, and `A` is ignored.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks like a 2-1 multiplexer.  It passes A or C to the output, depending on the value of B.

Comment: It's a multiplexer, but it's not a hazard-free one.  Even if A and C are true, a rising or falling edge may generate a glitch on the output.  A hazard-free multiplexer would include "A and C" as an extra term on the output "or" gate.

Answer (score 6):

Its a 2:1 multiplexer, the select input being B. A and C are inputs, D is the output